# Android web view local storage does not refresh on android 4.3 or less OS

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, local-storage

For an android webview application, a dynamic webview page (page A) loads items from local storage correctly when the page A loads for the first time. Then, on Page B another local storage item is added. Then, page A is loaded using window.location.herf= "page A". But, page A does not load the extra local storage item added on Page B. It seems like page A always loads from cache after the 1st time load. This problem happens with any android device or emulator running on any android 4.3 or less operating system.

NOTE:*************************
Page A refreshes correctly on an emulator running on android 4.4 or on chrome web.

---

So... I want a work around for any android OS 4.3 or less.

html.js function that dynamically fills content on page A

```
function ShowResults(value) {

     var overNight = getNetWork(value);  /// it the function to get local storage based on value key
  document.write('<li><a href="file:///android_asset /SettingEditProgram.html?overnightkey='+value+'">')
  document.write('<div class="column">')
  document.write('<div class="rectangle"><network>'+ overNight.network + '</network></br>')
  document.write('<program>'+ overNight.program +'</program></br>')
  document.write('<text>' + overNight.start +'-'+ overNight.end + '</text></br>')
  document.write('<text>' + overNight.demo + ', ' + overNight.region + '</text>')

  document.write('</div>')
  document.write('</div></a></li>')

    }
```

Page A:***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='-1'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/style.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="html.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});


    var parameters = $(location).attr('search');
    parameter = parameters.replace("?overnightkey=",""); 
    // 'Setting' data-attributes using setAttribute
    var newKey = document.getElementById("overnight");
    var oldValue = newKey.getAttribute("data-overnight",newKey);
    newKey.setAttribute("data-overnight",newKey); 
    var newKeyvalue ="oldValue="+oldValue+" newValue:"+newKey; 
    console.log("newKeyvalue");

});

</script>



</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="album-list">

<div id="headerBar">
<a href="file:///android_asset/MyShowsHomePage.html"><img class="goback"     src="file:///android_asset/img/ic_goback-web.png"></a>
<img class="appicon" src="file:///android_asset/img/ic_launcher-web.png"><p   class="apptitle">Program Setting</p>
<a href="file:///android_asset/SettingAddProgram.html"><img class="add"  src="file:///android_asset/img/ic_add-web.png"></a>
</div>

<div data-role="content">

 <ul id="overnight" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-overnight="0">

     <script>

     getIDs().forEach(ShowResults);

    </script>

 </ul>

</div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->


</body>
</html>
```

---

page B that set local storage and then re-direct to page A:

---

```
$('#savebutton').click(function() {

        var keyOverNight = localStorage.getItem("keyOverNightAll");

        var keyOverNightArray = new Array();

        if (keyOverNight) {
            try {
                keyOverNightArray = JSON.parse(keyOverNight); // use JSON3 to handle  multiple browsers/versions
            } catch (e) {
                //keyOverNightArray = new Array(); // for parse failure --> return an empty Array
                // do nothing
            }
        }


        //Get a new key for setting page based on the local storage
        //OvernightKeys
        var newKey;
        if (keyOverNightArray.length == 0)
        {
            newKey =1;
        }
        else
        {
            newKey= keyOverNightArray[keyOverNightArray.length-1]+1;
        }

        //Store the overnight key
        keyOverNightArray.push(newKey);

        localStorage.setItem("keyOverNightAll",JSON.stringify(keyOverNightArray));

        //Now store Program values into the newKey
        var overnightKey = "overNight"+ newKey.toString();

        var jsonOvernight = {"network": NetworkSelected, "program": ProgramSelected, "start": STimeSelected, "end": ETimeSelected, "region": RegionSelected, "demo": DemoSelected }
        localStorage.setItem(overnightKey, JSON.stringify(jsonOvernight));

        //window.location = "file:///android_asset/SettingHomePage.html";
        window.location.href = 'file:///android_asset/SettingHomePage.html?newKey='+newKey;
        //window.location.reload(true);

        });
```

---

Things I tried on Page A
Refreshed every 10 seconds.. It does not read the newest element from local storage.
Set the cache to no content
Set a new data-attribute everytime it comes to this page after adding an item on PageB
tricked page A to load a html.js script with time stamp on it.. eg. html.js?'+timeStamp+'somestring:"
reloads page A. then it runs infinitely.

If I closed the app, and re-run it, it will load the newest localstoarge items again only on the 1st load.

I've tried almost most of the stack over flow help.. Cannot find any answer yet.

Comment: getIDs() gets all keys for json local storage. Then,getNetWork(value) uses those keys to retrieve final local storage values in json format.

Answer (score 0):

check out targetSdkVersion.
I meet same problem. I set targetSdkVesrion to under 16. then sloved.